# Request token from ACS with AAD JWT token

Tags: jwt, azure-active-directory, acs

I have a native app registered in AAD and I've added it in ACS as identity provider. Now I would like to use the JWT token issued from AAD to request a token from ACS for service bus. I checked out this article: How to: [Request a Token from ACS via the OAuth WRAP Protocol][1]

[1]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh674475.aspx#BKMK_1 and it lists three ways of requesting token from ACS: Password, SWT and SAML. I'm wondering if it's supported or there's any example of requesting by using JWT token.

Answer (score 0):

As such ACS capabilities are being  moved to Azure active directory and AAD will soon be the one service for all authn/authZ and ACS will be sunset. So you need to follow the process or registering your app in AAD and then how to manually handle the JWT token response on successful authentication of request from the client application. It uses json web token handler.

Refer the sample here. [AAD JWT token handler sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-manual-jwt-validation/blob/master/README.md)
 Of course this is a sample with web api and you have to modify as per your application.

Comment: Another question is that I'm aware that AAD could also issue SAML token as I could see there's an SAML endpoint listed in the endpoint panel. Is there any examples of the SAML request from a native app?